# Python BeautifulSoup similar divs in the same container sorting

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was able to scrape the data I want, however since all the divs are in 1 container which is "content-body" when I get the results they are dumped as a whole ( you can test the code and see) as in  all the match_date then match then tourny.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from lxml import html
import requests
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
import itertools
import re
import sys
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime

urls =("http://www.esportsheaven.net/?page=match")
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(urls,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

tournament=soup.findAll('div',{'class':['content-body']})
match_time = soup.find_all("div", style = "width:10%; float:left;")
match = soup.find_all("div", style = "width:46%; float:left; margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%")
tourny = soup.find_all("div", style = "width:40%; float:left; overflow:hidden;")
for tag in tournament:
    for tag in match_time:
        print tag.text
    for tag1 in match:
        print tag1.text
    for tag2 in tourny:
        print tag2.text
    print '==============='
```

I have tried few other methods and loop but did not get the result I want what I want is:

match_date , match , tourny

==================

and loops on all of them I Need this to store the data in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parsing code is correct with respect to extracting the elements. However, your `find` methods for match_time, math and tourny should be with respect to the variable `tournament` and not `soup`. Searching anything with respect to the variable `soup` searches the entire document. Where as searching with respect to `tournament` searches only the content div which is what you are interested in.

If you look at the pages HTML, there is only one `div` with class `content-body`. So, a `find_all` call makes no sense. So we do:

```
tournament = soup.find('div',{'class':['content-body']})
```

Now we find all the match_times, match_names and tourny's

```
match_times = tournament.find_all("div", style = "width:10%; float:left;")
match_names = tournament.find_all("div", style = "width:46%; float:left; margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%")
tournys = tournament.find_all("div", style = "width:40%; float:left; overflow:hidden;")
```

The lengths of all the three arrays are the same. So we zip them to access them as follows:

```
for element in zip(match_times, match_names, tournys):
    print element[0].text, element[1].text, element[2].text
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: it can be made lot more easier if we use CSS Selectors